# How to convert NSString to Character in Swift?

Tags: string, swift, character, nstextfield

I want to convert NSString to Character in Swift.

I am getting a String from NSTextField, where I input a single character (Example "@"), I need this in Character type.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use Character class

```
var chars = [Character](str)
```

Answer (score 12):

this should be as simple as `let characterFromString = Character(textField.text)`.

`NSString` is automatically bridged to Swift's `String`, and the `Character` class has an init which accepts a single character `String`; see the documentation [here](http://swifter.natecook.com/type/Character/).

This requires that the input string contain a single grapheme cluster (i.e. a single character) and so you might want to validate your input before casting. A slightly more verbose version of the above would be:

```
let text = textField.text as String
if countElements(text) == 1 {
    let character = Character(text) 
    // do what you want
} else {
// bad input :-( 
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is nicer for a single character, +1.

Answer (score 1):

The `stringValue` of `NSTextField` actually returns a Swift string and not `NSString`:

```
let str = myTextField.stringValue // str is a String
```

You get the first element with

```
let ch = str[str.startIndex] // ch is a Character
```

A `NSString` would have to be converted to a Swift string first:

```
let nsString : NSString = "@"
let str = String(nsString)
let ch = str[str.startIndex]
```

Comment: @codester: Because the index of String has the type `String.Index` and not `Int`. The underlying reason is (probably) the handling of complex composite Unicode characters.

Comment: From `textfield` you get `String` so no need to convert explicitly to `String`

Comment: Why the down vote? – Please let me know if there is something wrong.

Comment: I have not downvoted.Whoever downvoted should comment.I do not know why downvoted this answer is also correct